# Can I get access to user information in Cognito, without a user token?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, twilio, amazon-cognito

I'm using a third party software that allows users to send text messages (`twilio/plivo`), and I wanted to verify that the phone number is valid and belongs to a user before posting it to `DynamoDB`.

I have an `EC2` instance set up running on `nodejs` that gets incoming text messages with phone number, so how would I go about cross checking this phone number with `cognito`, since it's done over a mobile text message and not through a website?

I'm using API gateway on our website to check if a user is indeed who they say they are, but since it needs a token to validate a user I don't think this is possible via text messages?

EDIT: It seems I can see all of my users, if they're verified, and their phone numbers. Surely there's some bash script I can write and invoke, that has administrator IAM rights with cognito to get this same access? Or maybe even do this using nodeJS?

Comment: oh and to make things worse, our dynamoDB table has partitionKey being the user UID, so how would I even properly associate this incoming text, and get their UID? With APi Gateway we used $context.authorizer.claims.sub

Comment: Probably someone will find this useful documentation in future. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out! on my EC2 instance that's private:

```
//aws cognito access
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'key',
    secretAccessKey: 'accessKey'
});
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;
const client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18', region: 'REGION'});

//cognito request things

var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'UserPoolID', /* required */
    AttributesToGet: [
        'sub',
        'email_verified'
        /* more items */
    ],
    Filter: 'phone_number="+someNumber"',
    Limit: 10
};

client.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data["Users"][0]["Attributes"]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably someone will find this useful documentation in future. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property